# Volume mapping visual studio 2019 to nuget package cache

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core

I don't use the inbuilt docker build inside of visual studio 2019 because it is too buggy.  Instead I build my own container and then attach VS2019 to it for debugging.

If I make a change to a single dependency (or a previous layer) then it will re-download all dependencies in order to rebuild the needed layers.

This is bandwidth/time intensive and the packages are already cached in local machine.

I have read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-build?view=vs-2019

It has interesting table explaining how the inbuilt feature maps folders:

[image]

How do I see what that mapping looks like?  I think If I add that volume mapping to my own compose file then it would greatly increase speed as it wouldn't have to re-download on each build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to see what exactly your docker container is mapped to, you can list docker containers via

```
docker ps
```

and then grab your containers id, and inspect it via

```
docker inspect <id>
```

I have a container running right now which does use the inbuilt VS toolset, so let's see what that one says about mounts:

```
...
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/host_mnt/c/Users/<name>/.nuget/packages",
            "Destination": "/root/.nuget/packages",
            "Mode": "ro",
            "RW": false,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        },
...
```

Okay, so this is the mount you're probably looking for.

In order to take a look at what VS does exactly, you can go to the 'obj' folder of your project, and then head to 'Docker'.

In here you will find the *actually interesting* file VS will use for the `docker-compose up` call, which is e.g. the `docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml` file. Here you will also find the release config, which does not contain the NuGet mount as it is actually building with `dotnet publish`.

So in the `docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml` file you can finally find the required path for the mount, which looks like this for my application:

```
    volumes:
  - ...
  - C:\Users\<name>\.nuget\packages\:/root/.nuget/packages:ro
```

Which is exactly what we found in the docker inspect.

I hope this helps.

Also, take a look at this article which goes into detail on how the whole docker setup VS uses works exactly:

https://www.scrum-tips.com/2017/12/27/understanding-docker-with-visual-studio-2017-part-2/